# Spring Integration migration issue

Tags: spring, filter, migration, spring-integration

I have this kind of chains at different places in my application:

```
<int:chain input-channel="updateAdministratorChannel">
    <int:filter expression="payload.isAdministatorPublished"/>
    <int:service-activator expression="..."/>
    <int:gateway request-channel="mergeEntityChannel"/>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter logger-name="..." expression="'...'"/>
</int:chain>
```

Everything was working fine with Spring Integration version 3.0.1.RELEASE. We decided to migrate to version 4.2.x and we have an issue with the filter : when the condition is false the system hangs (until it timeout i suppose).
In the end i had to add a discard channel and modify my chains like so:

```
<int:chain input-channel="updateAdministratorChannel">
    <int:filter expression="payload.isAdministatorPublished" discard-channel="defaultDiscardChannel"/>
    <int:service-activator expression="..."/>
    <int:gateway request-channel="mergeEntityChannel"/>
    <int:logging-channel-adapter logger-name="..." expression="'...'"/>
</int:chain>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="defaultDiscardChannel" header-name="replyChannel"/>
```

I've read the [Migration Guides](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-3.0-to-4.0-Migration-Guide) but i don't see anything about that.
Did i miss something ?

```
Spring version : 4.2.5.RELEASE
Spring Integration version : 4.2.6.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern isn't clear because the behavior is expected: when `filter` is used by default, a discarded message is just dropped.

Not sure what behavior you are expecting or what you are claiming is working in version `3.0.x`, but what I guess by your config that you have a messaging gateway in the beginning you expect some reply from your `<chain>`. Of course this is not possible when you do nothing on the filter level.

What you do with the `discard-channel` is the correct solution.

Another option would be possible with the `throw-exception-on-rejection="true"` and an `error-channel` on the `<gateway>` to catch those discarded messages there and resend as a reply.

Note: Spring Integration `4.2` is out of support already. It is recommended to upgrade at least to the `4.3.x` if can't to `5.0.x`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Indeed, the chain is used afterward in other chains as a gateway and in version 3.0.x when the condition in the filter is false, the flow in the inner chain is stopped but the outer chain flow continues.

Comment: I don't think there were any changes in this area since 3.0 but you can/should also set the gateway `default-reply-timeout` to `0` if there is a possibility that the downstream flow will not return a reply (as long as the downstream flow doesn't hand off the work to another thread, in which case, you want the calling thread to block until the reply is received).

Comment: Ok thank you for the tip, i will update all the filters i have with the discard channel.